# Implementing Functor for a parametric type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

Having this type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Rgb a = (Num a, Show a) => Rgb a a a
```

I'm perfectly able to implement `Show` typeclass:

```
instance Show (Rgb a) where
  show (Rgb r g b) = "Rgb (" ++ show r ++ "," ++ show g ++ "," ++ show b ++ ")"
```

But if I try to do the same with `Functor`:

```
instance Functor (Rgb a) where
  fmap f (Rgb r g b) = Rgb (f r) (f g) (f b)
```

I got the following output on **GHCi** REPL:

```
<interactive>;:1093:19:
  The first argument of ‘Functor’ should have kind ‘* > *’,
    but ‘Rgb a’ has kind ‘*’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Rgb a)’
```

I will certainly be happy with solution and explanation, but also a link to deepen theory tied to this question.

To overcome this problem I've (temporarly) wrote this function:

```
mapRgb :: (Num a, Num b, Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> Rgb a -> Rgb b
mapRgb f (Rgb r g b) = Rgb (f r) (f g) (f b)
```

But I really prefer have `fmap` implemented for `Rgb` type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Functor` instance shouldn't have a type argument:

```
instance Functor Rgb where
  fmap f (Rgb r g b) = Rgb (f r) (f g) (f b)
```

If you want to derive instances, including `Functor`, use the `DeriveFunctor` pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Rgb a = Rgb a a a                   -- NOTE: DO NOT CONSTRAIN DATA!
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor)
```

Also, type constraints on a datatype declarations are almost always useless. Constrain the *functions* that need those constraints.

---

The problem you've discovered is due to the type of types: *kinds*. We write kinds with `*`, and the `:kind` command in GHCi can help:

```
λ> :kind Int
Int :: *
λ> :kind Char
Char :: *
λ> :kind Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

All `Functor`s take a type argument, so they all look like this:

```
λ> :kind Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
λ> :kind IO
IO :: * -> *
```

`RGB` is of kind `* -> *`, but when you write `RGB a`, you apply `a :: *` to it, it becomes `RGB a :: *`, which doesn't make sense to the compiler.

This should now make sense to you:

```
The first argument of ‘Functor’ should have kind ‘* > *’,
  but ‘Rgb a’ has kind ‘*’
```

---

The reason it failed before when you tried to implement the functor instance is because of these constraints on your datatype:

```
-- Do not do this. This is poor Haskell.
data Rgb a = (Num a, Show a) => Rgb a a a
```

You should have written:

```
data Rgb a = Rgb a a a
```

And then added constraints on each instance:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (RGB a) where
    ...

instance (Num a) => Num (RGB a) where
    ...
```

And then your functor instance would have been fine.

Comment: Have you tried in GHCi your first proposal? I too tried removing type argument but compiler still refuse to accept change (to be honest I've tried it also before posting the question). :(

Comment: @gsscoder That's because you constrained the types in your datatype to `Num` and `Show`. That's a bad thing: you're using constraints incorrectly. [This](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) might explain why, but for now, **remove the constraints in your data declaration.** I'll add this into the answer.

Comment: Yes now I see, removing constraint it works; but I think that `DeriveFunctor` is a simplier path.

Comment: @gsscoder Certainly, but I would recommend working with typeclasses, at least as an exercise for the future.

Comment: excellent suggestion. After all HKT is what make Haskell type system different from most functional languages.

Comment: Is this really a datatype context? The position looks more like an existential. Aren't datatype contexts further to the left?

Comment: @dfeuer You might be right. I'm certainly not so sure myself, though this works for the explanation.